# VirtualBox - Linux Mint not starting - VT-x is not available

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, vt-x, vt-d

I am running a Linux Mint virtual machine on Windows 10, and getting the following error:
[image]

**Host system**

- Windows 10 Pro (10.0.19043 Build 19043)
- Dell G3 with Intel Core i5 10-300H CPU
- VirtualBox 6.0.24

**What I've tried so far**

- rebooting
- looking in BIOS - VT-d is enabled, there is no option for VT-x.

Note that I have also recently installed Windows Subsystem for Linux WSL2 with Ubuntu recently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issuing the following command and rebooting solved the problem:
`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

Answer (score 2):

Start up in BIOS.  Look for these settings:

Look at this article:

[VT-x settings](https://www.minitool.com/news/vt-x-is-not-available.html)

> Vt-x is not enabled in the BIOS settings. The machine’s CPU does not
> support vt-x. Hyper-V virtualization is enabled in Windows. Core
> location is enabled.

Solutions:

> Disable Hyper-V Virtualization. Disable Core Isolation from Windows
> Defender. Enable VT-X from BIOS Settings.

See if these work, or alternatively if your system will not run 64-bit guests.

Comment: I tried all three ways mentioned in that article, and it hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: That means your computer (and BIOS, UEFI setup) does not allow 64-bit guests.

Comment: Eventually, I tried the following command, and it worked: `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`